# event is not defined using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a box when a button is clicked and hide it when I click out of the box.

[image]

The code I did works in Chrome and IE, but it doesn't in Firefox *(I tested only in these three browsers)*. Firefox console shows me `ReferenceError: event is not defined`.

- `$('.button.open_login .bb')` is the **button**.
- `$('.button.open_login .panel_opened')` is the **panel**.

**Code:**

```
$(document).click(function(){
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.button.open_login .panel_opened').length) {
        if (site.ui.other.loginbox.is(":visible")){
            site.ui.other.loginbox.fadeOut(150);
        }
        else {
            if ($(event.target).closest('.button.open_login .bb').length){
                site.ui.other.loginbox.fadeIn(150);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).click(function(event){`?

Comment: You should refer to the event object that is passed as parameter of the event handler function. The global Event object is deprecated and doesn't work in all browser.

Comment: @j08691 ... I'm ashamed. If you want you can post it as an answer. It may be useful for another distracted like me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the event of the element being clicked you should pass a parameter to the click function, like:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
```